# How to transform the $L^2$ inner product on a sphere $T$ into an inner product on the unit sphere $S^2$ where $\alpha T = S^2$. for $\alpha>0$?

Tags: integration, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, spherical-coordinates, spheres

Let $S^2$ be the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and let $T$ be another sphere such that $\alpha T = S^2$, for some $\alpha >0$. Now consider the $L^2$ inner product over the surface of the sphere $T$,
$$
(f,g)_{L^2(T)} = \int_T f(x) \overline{g(x)} dx.
$$
How I can I transform this inner product to the unit sphere? That is what is
$$
(f,g)_{L(S^2)},
$$
in terms of $(f,g)_{L^2(T)}$, or equivalently what is $(f,g)_{L^2(T)}$ in terms of $(f,g)_{L(S^2)}$?

Comment: If $f, g : S^2 \to \mathbb{C}$ then functions $x \mapsto f(\alpha x)$ and $x \mapsto g(\alpha x)$ are functions $T \to\mathbb{C}$. So you could define $(f,g)_{L^2(S^2)} = (x \mapsto f(\alpha x), x \mapsto g(\alpha x))_{L^2(T)}$.

Comment: But that doesn't account for the change in size of the domain? I think there should be some scaling factor in the right hand side, as this is like a change of variables?

Comment: This all depends on the inner products you choose. What is the norm of the constant one function? It seems to me that you want this to give the volume of the sphere. In that case the relation between the two inner products is multiplication by the ratio of the volumes of the spheres $S^{2}$ and $T$. If you want to show this explicitly I would advise you to work in spherical coordinates.